# All browsers won't reload/refresh, even if Ctrl+F5 is pressed

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I'm working on a wordpress theme which is hosted on Hostgator.

Now whenever I add/remove a widget, then I reload the page altered, but nothing happened. Even if I press Ctrl+F5.

It happens on all browsers I tried: FF, Chrome, IE8. Clearing cache won't work either, on any browser.

Have you ever encountered the same? Are there any solutions? Would I be my system administrator?

Comment: Do you use the server cash in wordpress? If so, you have to clear it first and then refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a plugin like [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/)?

Cache plugins like this take dynamic content, php and database content, and make the cache out of static files.

If the cache isn't working right, it may not be updating your changes you have made.

Comment: Thank you zereglio, I did found out it was caused by Super Cache. I don't think our site need this plugin due to small usage therefore I disabled it. Thank you very much for your answer!